# How do I put Fontawesome icons in input "value" fields?

Tags: input, unicode, font-awesome

I am not using a button for this particular part of the code, only an input field (and any button I added isn't working) but I would like a calculator icon next to the word "Calculate" in the "value" field.

So far I have this:

```
value="&#xf1ec; Calculate"
```

But this is failing to reproduce the calculator icon (the code does turn blue as though it has been accepted but the icon fails to load).

f1ec is the unicode of the icon at Fontawesome. I can not seem to get a value that works and displays. Is there another way around this or have I done the unicode incorrectly?

Thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: Oh, I have found one that is working, so I was doing it right, but something not right with the unicode. 

Something like this works &#128423; (it's not a calculator shamefully).

Comment: I've decided to leave it with &#128505; a check box with a tick in it. It will do. Not quite keeping with the theme from Fontawesome. 

If someone has a work around so I can use the Fontawesome calculator, I would be keen to hear the solution.

Comment: Try `&#x1F5A9;` or  `&#128425;` for _Pocket Calculator_ emoji…

Comment: Yeah, I used a couple of different options, it's been a shame that they're not all working as expected on Android etc.

Comment: The `&#xf1ec;` (`U+F1EC` codepoint) belongs to a  _Private Use_ area in Unicode. Hence, it can be rendered merely in a font which _knows_ such a glyph…